# Quick way of looking up constructor dependencies for DI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependency-injection, constructor, ninject

I'm using Ninject to glue together a complex project and I want to refactor some of the dependencies so I can make better use of the factory pattern (as implemented in ninject.extensions.factory). I'm finding that quite a lot of my time is spent switching between screens/files to establish what constructor dependencies need to be satisifed to instantiate a specific type.

I'm wondering if any tool/extension/add-in/workflow exists to make my life a little easier.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?  Where is your time spent?  Creating registrations?

Comment: Hi @PhilSandler, it's quite simple really... Ideally, I'd like to hover over a type and view the constructor parameters for that type. This will save me a context switch of having to change windows in order to find this information. I'm after any tool/workflow that reduces the number of clicks required to look up this information.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now.  I don't know of anything that does what you're asking.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're really trying to do here as opposed to where you're stuck on the solution? It sounds like this entire refactoring could be done in an hour or two with a little reflection and CodeDom - but you first have to explain what it is that you want.

Comment: I'm trying to write ninject bindings. I'm looking for something to ease the huge amount of flipping between classes to establish the dependencies I need to satisfy in order for types to be built. Because of the large number of classes involved, I'm finding that with all the context switching, I'm losing track of what's going on. If I had easier access to constuctor parameters, such that I could look them up from the comfort of my binding module class, I wouldn't keep blowing up my crap memory!